# Hidden radio button but box around it in ie8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have style my radio buttons with a background image, basically what i have done is

```
<input type="radio" id="btn" name="btn" style="opacity: 0;filter: alpha(opacity = 0);position:absolute;">
<label for="btn">My Text</label> <!--- added styles to it --->
```

with this i get output something like this

```
Image1 that shows how the display should be: http://i39.tinypic.com/2vcyidg.png
```

It works fine in every browser except ie8, in ie8 it shows a dotted box around hidden buttons when a label is selected

```
Image2 shows the problems in ie8: http://i39.tinypic.com/j8l635.png
```

I cant choose the property display:none; as in IE browsers it disables the radio buttons  so i have to hide it.

How can i hide that dotted box in ie8?

Thank You.

Regards,

Shishant Todi.

Comment: I even tried adding border:0;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you can use javascript:

```
<input onfocus="this.blur()" type="radio" id="btn" name="btn" style="opacity: 0;filter: alpha(opacity = 0);position:absolute;" />
```

Comment: It worked but still there was a little blur showing/hiding so i did it left:-999px;

Comment: this is very, very hackish, which means it is likely to break if the stars don't align perfectly (IE version, js enabled, etc.). I'd highly sugggest figuring out why < input type="hidden" > is not working for you.

Answer (score 3):

Is there a reason why you're not using <input type="hidden" />?

Comment: Yes before i tried <input type="hidden" /> and i was successfully passing the values to form but dont know why everything else except Form Upload was not working.

Comment: I will be better if you find why everything is not working, and use hidden input.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where my radio buttons and checkboxes were showing borders, but only in IE. In my case, this was a css issue where these inputs were being treated the same as text inputs. I simply defined a new class in the stylesheet and specified a border of zero px.