# how to remove box around radio button in internet explorer8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I need to remove rectangular box around radio button in internet explorer 8.

**border: 1px solid #ccc;**

in chrome, radio button is showing correctly.

But in IE*8, its showing rectangular box around radio button because of border: 1px solid #ccc.

Kindly help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Try `<input type="hidden">`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hidden radio button but box around it in ie8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888876/hidden-radio-button-but-box-around-it-in-ie8)

Comment: try with `outline:0;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
border: none !important;
```

Or this:

```
border-width: 0 !important;
```