# IE 8 : Mysterious Box coming around Radio Button

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

In the below image - you see a mysterious box coming around Radio Button. 
Any ideas what can be done ?

[image]

Below is the styling applied :

```
.inline-radio {
    padding-top: 0px;
}

.inline-radio input[type="radio"] {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;    
}
```

Comment: What's the relevant HTML?

Comment: Clearly a border, try border:none;

Comment: That looks like the selection box, which shows which control has keyboard focus.  Not sure if there's anything you can do about that, other than center it more on the box when it has focus.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/889017/1585455

Comment: None of the duplicates marked solved my question

Answer (score 0):

Just from looking at your image, it looks like it has been ripped out of the layout as a result of `position: absolute`. One thing you could do, is `display: inline` instead. Not sure there is much to gain from absolute positioning without a `top` and `left` property.